# calculating a function using files

Tags: python, function, numpy, for-loop

I have written a python function for some calculation that uses below two data sets.I want to calculate z for every data in data_2 using row1,row2,ror3,row4,row5 of data_1.However, as i am new to python i tried to write but fails in between.please help.Thanks.

```
       data_1                                      data_2        
file    a    b    c    d                             x
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3                           0.5
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1                           0.8
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2                           0.9
```

my tried code is here:

```
import numpy as np
file1=np.loadtxt('data_1',skiprows=1,usecols=(1,2,3))
file2=np.loadtxt('data_2',skiprows=1,usecols=(0))

def calculation(a,b,c,x):
    z=(a+b+c)*x
    return z

for value in file2:
    print(value)
    calculation
```

my expected output should be something like

```
   data_3                                            
file    a    b    c    d       z                          
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -                     
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -                     
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -                     
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -                        
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -                       
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -
```

Comment: 1) remove "each" in your for loop, 2) you are calling calculation without arguments

Comment: `for each value in file2:` is not valid in python. It should be `for value in file2:`

Comment: please show me if possible i updated the code but output i am not getting as expected

Comment: You have mixed data types (string in first column) which is a bit easier to handle in `pandas` than directly in `numpy`. Can you use the pandas package?

Comment: @tdelaney yes i can

Comment: need help using numpy,....pandas is quite hard for me

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamic language and `numpy` tends to override normal operators to apply operations to entire collections of data. Often, if you have a `for` loop, you are not taking advantage of that.

`numpy` arrays can only hold a single data type but you have a string in column 0. `pandas` wraps `numpy` and makes multiple data types easier to deal with. So I've switch to reading `pandas.DataFrame` objects instead of arrays.

It looks like you want the cartesian product of `file2["x"]` with the rows in `file1`. One way to do that is to create a dummy column in both dataframes that have matching values and then merge. Use the `sum` method for `a + b + c` and then multiply with `x`, and you have the result.

```
import pandas as pd

# read space separated tables
file1=pd.read_table('data_1', sep=r"\s+")
file2=pd.read_table('data_2', sep=r"\s+")

# we want (a+b+c)*x, for each value in file2["x"]. Do the sum, then
# use `merge` with a temporary key to create the cartesian product 
# with x. For each `x`, merge will create a row for each matching
# key and since all keys match, we've got a cartesian product.
# Finally, multiply.
file1["_tmpsums"] = file1[["a", "b", "c"]].sum(axis=1)
file1["_tmpmergekey"] = file2["_tmpmergekey"] = 1
file1 = pd.merge(file1, file2, on="_tmpmergekey")
file1["z"] = file1["_tmpsums"] * file1["x"]
file1 = file1.drop(["_tmpsums", "_tmpmergekey", "x"], axis=1)

print("   data_3")
print(file1.to_string(col_space=6, index=False, justify="center"))
```

Result

```
   data_3
 file     a      b      c      d      z  
 file1   0.5    0.6    0.8    0.3   0.95 
 file1   0.5    0.6    0.8    0.3   1.52 
 file1   0.5    0.6    0.8    0.3   1.71 
 file1   0.2    0.2    0.4    0.1   0.40 
 file1   0.2    0.2    0.4    0.1   0.64 
 file1   0.2    0.2    0.4    0.1   0.72 
 file1   0.1    0.4    0.5    0.2   0.50 
 file1   0.1    0.4    0.5    0.2   0.80 
 file1   0.1    0.4    0.5    0.2   0.90
```

Comment: output is quite different from my one....can you please rectify your code so that output should be same

Comment: I'm not sure how different. I tweaked the output format. Hopefully that's close.

Comment: still different ....i need to calculate the function for each z value                                            
file    a    b    c    d       z                          
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -                     
file1  0.5  0.6  0.8  0.3      -                     
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -                     
file1  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.1      -                        
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -                       
file1  0.1  0.4  0.5  0.2      -

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm going to have to fiddle with this a bit.

Comment: is it possible using numpy please let me know...its quite hard to understand for me

Comment: numpy is a bit harder because of the "file" string column that needs to be in the result. You would do about the same thing with a,b,c and x. But then you wouldn't have the "file" column. You could generate that column while writing the file, but pandas already does that part for you, so nothing saved.

Comment: can we include the function i have written in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas as follows

```
import pandas as pd

# Load Data
data_1 = pd.read_csv('data_1.txt', delimiter = r"\s+")
data_2 = pd.read_csv('data_2.txt', delimiter = r"\s+")

# Compute the cartesian product of data_1 with data_2
# since for each row in data_1, we need sequence of rows in data_2
# We do this using DataFrame merge by injecting a key that is repeated for each row
# i.e. 'merge_key'
data_1['merge_key'] = pd.Series([1]*len(data_1))
data_2['merge_key'] = pd.Series([1]*len(data_2))
df = pd.merge(data_1, data_2, on = 'merge_key')
# Drop merge key from result
df.drop('merge_key', axis = 'columns', inplace = True)

# DataFrame df now has columns File, a, b, c, d, x
# We can apply function calulation to each row using apply
# and specifying the columns to send to calculation
df['z'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculation(row['a'], row['b'], row['c'], row['x']), axis = 'columns')

# Drop x column
df.drop('x', axis = 'columns', inplace = True)

# Write to CSV file
df.to_csv('data_3.txt', index=False, sep = " ")
```

**Output**

Pandas DataFrame df

```
    file    a   b   c   d   z
0   file1   0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 0.95
1   file1   0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 1.52
2   file1   0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 1.71
3   file1   0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.40
4   file1   0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.64
5   file1   0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.72
6   file1   0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.50
7   file1   0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.80
8   file1   0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.90
```

CSV File data_3.txt

```
file a b c d z
file1 0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 0.9500000000000001
file1 0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 1.5200000000000002
file1 0.5 0.6 0.8 0.3 1.7100000000000002
file1 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.4
file1 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.6400000000000001
file1 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.7200000000000001
file1 0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.5
file1 0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.8
file1 0.1 0.4 0.5 0.2 0.9
```

**Basic Python**

Same output

```
# Get data from first file
with open('data_1.txt', 'r') as f:
    # first file header
    header1 = f.readline()
    
    # Let's get the lines of data
    data_1 = []
    for line in f:
        new_data = line.rstrip().split()  # strip '\n' and split on parens
        for i in range(1, len(new_data)):
            new_data[i] = float(new_data[i])  # convert columns after file to float
        data_1.append(new_data)
  
# Get data from second file
with open('data_2.txt', 'r') as f:
    # second file header
    header2 = f.readline()
    
    # Let's get the lines of data
    data_2 = []
    for line in f:
        new_data = float(line.rstrip())  # only one value per line
        data_2.append(new_data)


with open('data_3.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Output file
    # Write Header
    f.write("file a b c d z\n")
    
    # Use double loop to loop through all rows of data_2 for each row in data_1
    for v1 in data_1:
        # For each row in data_1
        file, a, b, c, d = v1  # unpacking the values in v1 to individual variables
        for v2 in data_2:
            # for each row in data_2
            x = v2  # data2 just has a single value per row
           
            # Calculation using posted formula
            z = calculation(a, b, c, x)
            
            # Write result
            f.write(f"{file} {a} {b} {c} {d} {z}\n")
```

**Numpy Version**

```
import numpy as np
file1=np.loadtxt('data_1.txt',skiprows=1,usecols=(1,2,3, 4))
file2=np.loadtxt('data_2.txt',skiprows=1,usecols=(0))

with open('data_3.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Write header
    f.write("file a b c d z\n")
    
    # Double loop to through the values of file1 and file2
    for val1 in file1:
        for val2 in file2:
            # Only use first 3 values (val1[:3] to only use first 3 value so ignore d)
            z = calculation(*val1[:3], val2)  # *val[:3] is unpacking values to go into calculation
            # Write result
            # map(str, val1) - converts values to string
            # str(z) converts z to string
            #' '.join([*map(str, val1), str(z)] - creates a space separated string
            f.write(' '.join([*map(str, val1), str(z)]) + "\n")
```

Comment: its fine but where is the function that calculates the same

Comment: is it possible using numpy please let me know...its quite hard t understand for me

Comment: @anonymossi--`df['z'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculation(row['a'], row['b'], row['c'], row['x']), axis = 'columns')` uses your calculation function.  Since you stated you just started with Python I'll make another version using simpler functions.

Comment: @anonymossi--updated with a version that uses basic Python.  Does this make sense?